# TFS 2015 Visual Studio Test Test Assembly multiple paths

Tags: tfsbuild, tfs-2015, vstest

Using TFS 2015 Build ...
I understand how wildcards work and I've read the formatting documentation, but I don't get expected results when using them in the Test Assembly field of the Visual Studio Test step.

Individually each of these paths work but when placed together with a semicolon I get the error: "**The given path’s format is not supported**."
$(build.sourcesDirectory)\v7.25_Core**\MySystems.Xmts.Test\bin**\MySystems.Xmts.Test.dll; $(build.sourcesDirectory)\v7.25_Core**\MySystems.Xmts.WinForms.Test\bin**\MySystems.Xmts.WinForms.Test.dll

Again, each work individually.  Together with a semicolon they should work together but I get an error.  What am I missing?

Documentation says it should work: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/test/visual-studio-test

This is also of interest regarding wildcards: https://blogs.infosupport.com/tfs2015-build-tasks-the-wildcard-format-explained/#comment-124376

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this is a known bug and is solved with TFS2015 UPDATE 3.
"VsTest task fails if full path of 2 DLLs are given separated by semicolon."

Comment: Please add the source for this known bug.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `$(build.sourcesDirectory)` to `**`, you'll get rid of this error:

```
**\v7.25_Core**\MySystems.Xmts.Test\bin**\MySystems.Xmts.Test.dll; **\v7.25_Core**\MySystems.Xmts.WinForms.Test\bin**\MySystems.Xmts.WinForms.Test.dll
```

Comment: I had already tried that on another earlier attempt.  I tried once more and I get the same error:
Executing the powershell script: C:\Build\tasks\VSTest\1.0.30\VSTest.ps1
## **[error]The given path's format is not supported.**
##[warning]No test assemblies found matching the pattern: 'F:\Builds\_work\1\s\v7.25_Core\**\MySystems.Xmts.Test\bin\**\My.Xmts.Test.dll; F:\Builds\_work\1\s\v7.25_Core\**\MySystems.Xmts.WinForms.Test\bin\**\MySystems.Xmts.WinForms.Test.dll'.

Comment: I've tested with TFS 2015.3. When use $(build.sourcesDirectory) in Visual Studio Test step, I would get "The test source file provided was not found" error. But if I use ** instead of $(build.sourcesDirectory) as I mentioned, I'll get a successful result.